# Regex inside a word, containing given characters

Tags: python, regex

If I have a text (e.g. `This is g56875f562f624g64a4b54a4g51bb3`) how can I match the substrings of it that are made up of [a,b,0-9], are of length 5, contain at least one letter (a or b) and don't start or end with a space (so `51bb3` shouldn't be matched since it's at the end of the string)?

The matches in the example would be `64a4b`, `4a4b5`, `a4b54`, `4b54a` and `b54a4`.

I want to use Python.

Comment: Are you sure you want a regexp that does it all? `[ab0-9]{5}(?!\s)` would give you all conditions but one, then you could check `if 'a' in value or 'b' in value` using plain Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by matching exactly 5 occurences of [a,b,0-9]:

```
[ab0-9]{5}
```

Then wrap it in a lookahead so that it can produce overlapping matches:

```
(?=([ab0-9]{5}))
```

Then add another lookahead that asserts that there's an `a` or a `b` somewhere within the next 5 characters:

```
(?=.{,4}[ab])(?=([ab0-9]{5}))
```

And finally add lookarounds that assert the absence of whitespace:

```
(?<!\s)(?<!^)(?=.{,4}[ab])(?=([ab0-9]{5})(?!\s|$))
```

See also the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/5xL3Ar/2).